# sp_BlitzCache and missing index but index columns are already there

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have this recommendation as a missing index on a table for a stored procedure that is ran from the script tool `sp_BlitzCache`.  However I have an index on the columns `TeamId`, `PlayerId`, and `Active` already. Shouldn't this be used instead and not duplicate indexes with the same columns?

The query must be this inline select

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Schema.TeamPlayer WHERE TeamId = dt.Id AND Active = 1) AS PlayerCount
```

**Current Index**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TeamPlayerActive
 ON [Schema].[TeamPlayer] ([TeamId], [PlayerId], [Active]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=100, ONLINE=?, SORT_IN_TEMPDB=?, DATA_COMPRESSION=?);
GO
```

**Missing Index Message**

```
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve query cost (34.7976)
by 12.5436% for 12196 executions of the query over the last 6 hours


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_Active_Includes
 ON [Schema].[TeamPlayer] ([Active])
INCLUDE ([TeamId]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=100, ONLINE=?, SORT_IN_TEMPDB=?, DATA_COMPRESSION=?);
GO
```

Comment: The order of the index key columns matter. I'm guessing `Active` is not the first column in your existing index whereas the missing index suggestion wants `Active` as the first column, plus `TeamId` as the second key or included column.

Comment: Really? I thought SQL Server was smart enough to figure this out?

Comment: What indexes do you have exactly? Please script them as create.

Comment: Note the index is an ordered b-tree. Consider a phonebook with names ordered by last name and first name. That order is quite useful to find people with the last name Flynn but you need to scan the entire book to find people with first name Mike. You would need 2 different books (i.e. indexes) to locate by either method efficiently.

Comment: It's just a suggestion. You are free to ignore it if the improvement is not significant. It seems highly likely that the proportion of values (only 2 exist i'm guessing based on the name) changes slowly but certainly over time from mostly active (1) to mostly inactive(0). Perhaps a filtered index is what you really want for most "general" queries.

Comment: I added the current index I have on the table

Comment: Can you post the FULL query instead of the subquery which you assume is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it seems, that you want to look up `TeamId` and `Active`. Index on `(TeamId, PlayerId, Active)` is not exact match. You can seek the `TeamId` but then you have to scan through all `PlayerIDs` in that team. Both active and inactive, which is a bit wastefull. How much wastefull depends on the ratio of active records. For exact seek you would need index on `(TeamId, Active, ...)` or `(Active, TeamId, ...)`.

Given the suggested index the situation is probably a bit different. The server seems to look for all active records, you are probably looking for all teams in one query. In that case the best index is `(Active, TeamId)` or, as suggested, `(Active) with TeamId included`. All active records are stored consecutively here. `(Active, TeamId)` is more versatile though, as it is already pre-grouped by `TeamId`. Index on `(TeamId, Active)` is in principle usable, but you would have to seek for all teams individually, which is suboptimal and chances are, the server would revert to scan anyway, so you would end up where you already are.

Index on `(Active, TeamId)` is clearly best here. I would make it filtered on only active records if you do not need to look for inactive records frequently.